# reference matches in a string gsub regexp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Say I have a string like this

```
"some3random5string8"
```

I want to insert spaces after each integer so it looks like this

```
"some3 random5 string8"
```

I specifically **want to do this using `gsub`** but I can't figure out how to access the characters that match my regexp.

For example:

```
temp = "some3random5string8"
temp.gsub(/\d/, ' ')  # instead of replacing with a ' ' I want to replace with
                      # matching number and space
```

I was hoping there was a way to reference the regexp match. Something like `$1` so I could do something like `temp.gsub(/\d/, "#{$1 }")` (note, this does not work)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the `gsub` docs:

> If replacement is a String it will be substituted for the matched
>   text. It may contain back-references to the pattern’s capture groups
>   of the form \d, where d is a group number, or \k, where n is a
>   group name. If it is a double-quoted string, both back-references must
>   be preceded by an additional backslash.

This means the following 3 versions will work

```
>> "some3random5string8".gsub(/(\d)/, '\1 ')
=> "some3 random5 string8 "
>> "some3random5string8".gsub(/(\d)/, "\\1 ")
=> "some3 random5 string8 "
>> "some3random5string8".gsub(/(?<digit>\d)/, '\k<digit> ')
=> "some3 random5 string8 "
```

Edit: also if you don't want to add an extra space at the end, use a negative lookahead for the end of line, e.g.:

```
>> "some3random5string8".gsub(/(\d(?!$))/, '\1 ')
=> "some3 random5 string8"
```

A positive lookahead checking for a "word character" would also work of course:

```
>> "some3random5string8".gsub(/(\d(?=\w))/, '\1 ')
=> "some3 random5 string8"
```

Last but not least, the simplest version without a space at the end:

```
>> "some3random5string8".gsub(/(\d)(\w)/, '\1 \2')
=> "some3 random5 string8"
```

Comment: i actually went with `"some3random5string8".gsub(/(\d)/, '\1 ').rstrip` because that was easier for me to understand. thanks for the great answer.

Answer (score 5):

`gsub`takes a block, which for me is easier to remember than the block-less way of getting the match.

```
"some3random5string8".gsub(/\d/){|digit| digit << " "}
```

Comment: a little too verbose for my tastes but thanks for teaching me something useful to know!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about ruby syntax, but:

```
temp.gsub(/(\d)/, '$1 ')
```

or

```
temp.gsub(/(\d)/, '\1 ')
```

To be sure you insert space between number and a non number(i.e. letter or special char):

```
temp.gsub(/(\d)(\D)/, '$1 $2')
```

Comment: sorry but in ruby 1.9 at least the `$` versions don't seem to work. tried with both single and double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with ruby, but I expect you can capture the digit, and then insert into replacement like this...

```
temp.gsub(/(\d)/, '$1 ')
```